# Conditional redirect from old domain/page to new

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect certain pages on old domain to specific pages on new domain and those that don't match, just to the new domain. I am able to put .htaccess on the old domain.

Tried this but can't seem to get it to work...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^somepagename [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com/new-page [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^tools/old.htm [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com/usabilitynet/tools-new [L,R=301,NC]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%{REQUEST_URI}` always starts with `/`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/somepagename [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com/new-page [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tools/old.htm [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com/usabilitynet/tools-new [L,R=301,NC]
```

You should also escape `.`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tools/old\.htm [NC]
```

But you can make it simpler:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^somepagename https://www.newdomain.com/new-page [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^tools/old\.htm https://www.newdomain.com/usabilitynet/tools-new [L,R=301,NC]
```